# why does my particle animation react like that?

Tags: particles, hair

So i have made a simple ring, gave hair to it and an object.

And it simulates like this:

[image]

And i have no idea why?

Why isn't it just hanging down?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/24s22xyzrx058c4/particle_hair_physics_probl.blend?dl=0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hair direction is Y-axis of your object direction,similar to the bone in pose mode.
in pic1, the object direction is (0,0,0) downwards,means -Z, and the face normal is out,they can't match.So we first rotate it to Y-axis,apply the rotation.And then,try to make the faces whose normal is the direction we want,so I make a circle,facing downwards,that's ok.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean like so?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Orf.png.  doesn't help. And the origin was at the end of the line.... and what do you mean with "turn direction to z"?

Comment: I can make it,I just editing my answer,but gif is alway over2M, that's waste many time.

Comment: i don't need a gif, but an understandable answer....and i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/354b9a7673984c60bd6e31ce428c3520  in your file,the origin is not at the end of the line, and the hair direction is related to the normal direction.

Comment: I really made it, and it's just the communication problem. You down vote it so quickly, it's a bad action, when facing something you don't agree or understand,try to think twice and judge later.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwRE7.gif. -> here is my origin of my original file. Yes i downvoted it because your first answer was really bad. I will upvote it if it helps me. And i don't know what you mean with the origin is not at the end of the line!? it is...i think

Comment: I don't know why the ball in my file is lied not vertical, and now I download again, it's ok.Any way ,it's the reason of the normal direction of your circle.

Comment: i didn't change my upload - it is exactly the same as i wrote my question. If it would that i have changed it (what you are assuming) then my link and my question would be edited - which it isn't. And that was what i didn't like at your answer: you claim something wrong. And even if i make my circle like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veisa.png ...it still doesn't work. So no, your answer is still not solving my problem

Comment: but you are still claiming wrong things in your answer which everybody can approve who downloads my file - which wasn't ever changed of me.

Comment: I have upload my profile, you can have a try.

Comment: I never say you change it, I just say in the beginning, it shows different on my computer,I don't know why,that's the explaination why I want to change the origin.And no mater what, I can make it, I just tell you the way I do it.

Comment: thank you for updating the answer. But i am convinced you did something with my file which you didn't provide in the answer. because my result is still: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlluX.png [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4svvb.png

Comment: And maybe you should delete you bake and run the animation again.

Comment: i did. several times. it is pretty weird. if my circle is flat (0 degrees), nothing is happening at all. If i rotate it, it moves...but wrong. i have no idea why. but i wouldn't mind if you upload your blend file, if it is working....maybe i see a difference to mine

Comment: I reproduce it again,and I got why,I will update the answer.Let me try to reproduce it again,pls wait.

Comment: updated!!!!!!!!

Comment: thanks for your update. Ok, now they are hanging downwards. But if you try to animate it...it still is totally wrong. That's why i made that animated gif in my question. Try animating x rotation of the ring. you will get: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA8RI.gif do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PjL5Chh, the root direction of hair is alway the same as normal(in green), and the others will combine the influence of root and gravity,so you can't make it totally downwards, but if you raise the hair segement,it will look much more downwards. To fix it,give me some time ,I'll have a try.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Chris's extra request shown in the comment.I tried many ways,but no one is both perfect and simple,I'll show my ways in brief,it all depends on what kind of result you want.

1. Simple and almost Perfect:
   Just increase the segment of hair,cause you don't need thousands of ball,so add the segment to a big number(40 is almost looks good) will not cause too much exhaust.Only the direction of hair root is fixed,others will have much influence by gravity.
   But,it's not perfect,cause if you watch close,the rope is not absolutely vertical,but I think it's OK for your purpose.
   I have thought about changing the direction of normal,to fix the problem thoroughly,but I find something strange,it waste me much time.
   I can only change the normal of line(edit mode-Alt+N),but the hair direction is only related to the normal of faces or vertices,as you can see in Particle System,which I can't change.Any one could help to tell me why?
   [image]
   [image]
2. I make a chain to control the ball,chain is made by cloth,but need a little more work.It can show the filament in detail, but I think you don't need that.The problem is,I don't know how to bind a heavy ball to the cloth which makes the whole system looks real.
   [.blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/ddd2e9e58ae54104936afbdc3008549a)